# QML: public variable

Tags: qt, qml

I have two QML files. 
In **First.qml** I can make visible Second.qml. In Second.qml I have **selectedParts** variable. 
I want to set **selectedParts** to value **1** always, when I make **Second.qml** visible. That works only when I load 
**Second.qml** for first time. If I make **Second.qml** invisible and then visible, **selectedParts** value is **2**. Is there  anyway 
to make **selectedParts** variable public and set its value always when I click on myImage?

**First.qml**

```
Item {
    Image {
        id: myImage
        MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                    second.visible = true
...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second.qml**

```
Item {
    property int selectedParts: 1
    Image {
        id: myImage2
        MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                    selectedParts = 2
...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way from `First.qml` to increment `selectedParts` (as long as there's no other - not shown code - affecting the variable). Also,  `selectedParts` is accessible as a top level variable in the code making it visible to `First.qml`. If you have a specific problem in your code post *that* code.  Anyhow, to set the variable to `2` when the component is visible, you can do it inside `onVisibleChanged`, i.e. `onVisibleChanged: if(visible) selectedParts = 2`. If you have variables in inner scopes, consider [aliases](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html).

Comment: So what happens if you just do `second.visible = true; second.selectedParts = 1;` in `First`?

Comment: hyde variable selectedParts is not accesible in First.qml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding back button into the Second.qml file. And in this button I put statement selectedParts = 1.

Answer (score 2):

QML public variable? Look up for MessageBoard in [Defining QML types from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html). We are using that approach. All you need is to create C++ MessageBoard object, put some data in there and reference it via the QML context given to every QML root object:

```
m_quickView.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myMsgBoard", MyQmlMsgBoard::instance());
```

And in QML:

```
Rectangle {
    id: topRect
    scale: myMsgBoard.scale // or anywhere in QML
    // ....
}
```

Of course that "message board" C++ object exposes to QML something like:

```
Q_PROPERTY(qreal scale READ scale CONSTANT);
```